# How to install luasockets on imx6 processor running openWRT linux

Tags: lua, installation, embedded-linux, openwrt, luasocket

I am new to linux and am working on a project that uses a imx6 processor and has the openWRT linux distribution running on it. I am trying to send UDP messages to the processor using luasockets, but I am having trouble installing it installing it. The processor came with lua 5.1 installed on it, but the module luasockets is not on it. I am using putty as the terminal emulator to access the processor. I don't have internet access on the processor so I can't use the package manager to install luasockets. Does anyone know a way I can download and install the luasockets module manually on the processor? I have USB access to the processor so I can load software on the processor that way. Thanks, any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If(!) there is an luasockets package for openwrt you can copy it to your device via USB. From there you can install it with the opk command line tool.
If there is no such package you will have to build and package it yourself.

Comment: Yeah I tried with the opk tool but it didnt work. Do you know how i build and package manually?

Answer (score 0):

To write file with

```
cat << EOF > file
data
EOF
```

You can rebuild firmware itself https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/build.